# What is the best approach to perform face recognition in Windows 10 for a Universal Application?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, face-recognition, windows-10

Real-time face recognition is a relatively non-trivial process and as a result most people use a range of popular libraries, such as OpenCV. However, there seem to be few options for targetting Windows 10 platforms for Universal Applications.

Support [now seems to be available](https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/08/20/opencv-support-for-windows-universal-apps-now-available-on-github/) for OpenCV and Universal Apps but I have had quite a bit of difficulty getting this setup and I really only require the face recognition features.

What libraries currently provide support for developing real-time face recognition applications for Windows 10 and Universal Applications?

Answer (score 0):

I would go down the OpenCV route, it's the most popular one so there is a lot of support for it if your problem isn't platform specific.

If there's no requirement for offline use, checkout [Project Oxford](http://projectoxford.ai/face), it's really cool.

Alternatively, if javascript is an option, there are a whole lot of libraries out there. I've used [headtrackr](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr), which worked well with Windows 8/WinJS 1.0.